# set backend url after extracting it from header azure apim

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway, azure-appservice

Hi I am trying to implement such a functionality where i need to make sure that the api is going through gateway so  have created a apim and i need to extract header from the call and route to that call :
so far i have done this policy:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <set-variable name="host" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("uri","http://google.com/"))" />
        <set-backend-service base-url="${{ variables.host}}" />
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

but its giving error :

```
Error in element 'set-backend-service' on line 16, column 4: Value is not a valid absolute URL.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error in element 'set-backend-service' on line 16, column 4: Value is not a valid absolute URL.

This probably means that the value of your uri header does not include https://. A valid absolute URL contains all the information necessary to locate a resource, including the protocol (HTTPS).

You can also set the value directly in the set-backend-service without using the set-variable first. Like:

`<set-backend-service base-url="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("header-name","optional-default-value"))" />`

Answer (score 0):

```
<set-backend-service base-url="@((string)context.Variables["host"])" />
```

Comment: @Ayush have you tried it?

Comment: i tried it . i dint get any error in the start but apim failed with 500 error

Comment: error in trace was the same set-backend-service (1.991 ms)
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "message": "Expression value is invalid.",
            "expression": "(string)context.Variables[\"host\"]",
            "value": "undefined",
            "details": "Value is not a valid absolute URL."
        },
        "Expression value is invalid. Value is not a valid absolute URL."
    ]
}

Comment: seems like we can not pass variable in backend service base url